# Why doesn't DynamoDB local recognize -shareDB option?

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

I'm trying to start a DynamoDB Local Docker container with the -shareDb option but it failes with the message "*Error while parsing options.  Unrecognized option: -shareDb*".

The docker image is from amazon/dynamodb-local and I'm starting using a docker-compose file.

The container starts okay without the -shareDb option.

Below is the docker-compose file I'm using:

```
version: '3'
services:
  dynamodb:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local  
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -shareDb -dbPath ."
  app:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html , its not `-shareDb` but `-sharedDb`

Comment: Wow.  I won't comment on how much time I spent looking into the issue without noticing that!  Thanks - marking as answer.

Comment: @JonathanSK - the little issues are usually the worst one in programming. Its either hard to see them or hard to trigger them :).